# Redirect user based on device with Javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a website, with a webpage. I want the webpage to be viewable by mobile devices ONLY. 

I know there are ways to redirect a *mobile-device-user* to the 'mobile' page, but on the mobile page is there a way to redirect a computer user away? (so that it is impossible for a computer to see the mobile page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the user agent then redirect the client to somewhere you want. See if it helps you: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html